# replacing .join() using python

Tags: python

I am learning python and was going through my tutorial. I came across this code segment and want to know if it can be replaced using a simple loop without using inbuilt .join()

```
return choice("".join(x * y for x, y in items))
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The big question is: Why? The `join` function does a loop inside the implementation, which is optimized nicely to be at least as fast as any loop you could write in Python (e.g., it's much faster in CPython, only slightly faster but still faster in PyPy…), and has the same effect. So, why would you want to write code that's more verbose, harder to get write, and slower?

Comment: I have a feeling [this might come in handy - this looks like an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @InbarRose: I suspect it may actually be a case of "I want to figure out how to implement `join` on my own" (or "I was given an assignment to implement `join` on my own") for learning purposes, in which case it's a reasonable question… but you're right that, as written, the question is probably an XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

```
value = ''
for x, y in items:
    value += x * y
return choice(value)
```

but know that this will be slower as you now have to build a new string value for each and every iteration over `items`. The `''.join()` only has to build *one* new string object.

If `choice()` is `random.choice()`, `x` is a string and `y` an integer, and this is a weighted random choice function, you should also be able to use a list:

```
value = []
for x, y in items:
    value += list(x) * y
return choice(value)
```

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work for list of tuples. I am writing a code to generate a string of weighted choice of a given tuple. Here is the code:def genseq(items):
    return choice("".join(x * y for x, y in items))

Comment: Following up on the "slower" bit: Python doesn't guarantee that `+=` is better than quadratic (it happens to be linear with recent CPython 2.x versions and all 3.x implementations, but the 2.x docs explicitly say not to count on that…). So, if you _really_ need something with guaranteed linear performance, and for some reason can't use `join`, the only option is to create a `StringIO` and `write` to it, then call `getvalue` on it when you're done.

Comment: @Rachel: This works in exactly the same cases your original code works. In particular, if `items` is a list of tuples, your original code will raise a `TypeError` from the `join` call, and Martijn's code will raise the same `TypeError` from the `+=`.

Comment: @Rachel: If my code doesn't work then yours doesn't either; there is no functional difference between the two.

Comment: @Rachel: You'll have to show me the *input* to your function if you want this corrected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No. Sure, if you're using CPython 2.x, you should always use `cStringIO` rather than `StringIO`, but that's not the issue here. Python 2.x does not guarantee better than quadratic string concatenation, so you should _always_ use `StringIO` or `cStringIO`. And the only difference between the two is that `cStringIO` loops in C instead of Python. Either way, it's not the same code path (at least as far as the language definition is concerned.)

Comment: @abarnert: Actually, I was wrong; even `StringIO.StringIO` uses a buffer and `''.join()` to concatenate the written strings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Meanwhile, in CPython 2.5-2.7 (I think it was 2.5; I could be misremembering), string concatenation happens to do something pretty similar to `StringIO`, but that's explicitly not guaranteed by the Python 2.x language, it's just a nice optimization that later CPython 2.x versions do (and PyPy—but not, e.g., Jython 2.5, which has a completely different optimization, the same one that was in Jython 2.3, which did not change at all in 2.5).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: When you say "`StringIO.StringIO` uses a buffer and `''.join()`", I assume you're talking about the specific implementation in CPython 2.5-2.7, right? I'm willing to bet that nothing in the Python 2.7 or 3.4 language guarantees that, and it's not true in CPython 3.x, and it's not true in Jython 2.3 or 2.5.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, I am looking at CPython 2.7.x here; 3.x has `io.StringIO` instead now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Anyway, the point is that, in 2.x, `StringIO` is guaranteed to do something non-quadratic (obviously `cStringIO` will be better in CPython, but that isn't relevant here), while string concatenation is not (even if it happens to be not too bad in 2.7), so when your answer says "slower" it should be read as not just "has a larger multiplier" but "may even be unnecessarily quadratic".